# Where to publish data (tar.gz) to be able to download it with `wget` (a service for hosting datasets)

Tags: computer-science, data-sharing

I have a 1GB tarred dataset that I wish to publish using a dedicated service (such as figshare or OSF.io) that hosts such databases, and additionally, e.g., counts the downloads.

My wish is to be able to download the dataset with `wget` command - to use it in a Jupyter Notebook.

Problems with the services tested so far: figshare -- the 1GB upload is stuck at 96-98% (tried a couple of times), and on OSF I was unable to download the dataset with `wget`.

I am aware that I could just use GDrive, Dropbox, or Github repository, but I'd like to have an external service for that, for two reasons:

1. People don't download it from "my" resources;
2. Count the number of downloads.

Do any of you know any other services that ship the functionalities I mentioned?

Comment: I am not sure if this question fits the purpose or guideline of this site. There are probably other stack exchange sites that could answer this question better.

Comment: There might be sites appropriate for your particular discipline. If that field has a SE site, ask there.

Comment: Is this related to Academia? We do have questions about hosting e.g. data for papers https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/187292/where-should-i-host-software-for-individual-papers if you're interested. But trying to drill into "can access with wget" seems out of scope.

Comment: FWIW Zenodo appears to support wget: https://github.com/zenodo/zenodo/issues/1629

Comment: Are you sure that this doesn't have to do with a limit on file sizes. I'm just guessing here, but 1000 is 97% of 1024 ... so if you have calculated your 1Gb based on a 1024 unit, and figshare calculate it on a 1000 unit AND (and here I'm unsure) there is a 1Gb file size limit then your upload WILL get stuck at somewhere between 96 and 98%

Comment: Thank you, I will try Zenodo. Figshare stucked randomly on: 94%, 96, or 98%.

Comment: SO on GitHub: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668239/how-do-i-track-file-download-count ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70062726/github-get-download-count-from-specific-file

Comment: Also a good idea, especially that Zenodo doesn't seem to count `wget` downloads (only button clicks), or it takes some time to count/update the download, thank you semmyk

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org) supports both: downloading with `wget`, and counting the number of downloads/views.

Special thanks to [@saritonin](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/152788/saritonin) for pointing me it that direction. To be honest, I completely forgot about Zenodo. :)